# proving adding even functions gets you even functions

Tags: functions

Part 1 
Let $f(x) = ax^n$, where $a$ is any real number. Prove that $f$ is even if $n$ is an even integer. (Integers can be negative too)

Part 2
Prove that if you add any two even functions, you get an even function

I'm confused as to how you would prove adding two even functions would get you an even function.

Comment: $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

Comment: Why was this downrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part 1) 
$$f(x)=ax^n$$
So, let $n=2k$. Then,
$$f(x)=ax^n=a(x^2)^k$$
Obviously, $x^2$ is an even function ($(-x)^2=x^2$). So,
$$f(x)=ax^n=a(x^2)^k$$
is an even function.

Part 2)
Let $f(x),g(x)$ be two even functions. Then,
$$f(x)=f(-x),\qquad g(x)=g(-x)$$
Adding the two gives
$$f(x)+g(x)=h(x)$$
Using the above relation then gives
$$f(x)+g(x)=h(x)=f(-x)+g(-x)$$
The last expression is $h(-x)$. We have therefore shown that $h(x)$ is even. Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Just out of curiosity, if you composed any two odd functions, what would you get and how would you prove it?

Comment: Say $f(x),g(x)$ are odd. Then, $f(-x)=-f(x)$, and the same holds for $g(x)$. Thus, $f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(g(x))$, or $(f\circ g)(-x)=-(f\circ g)(x)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much! Your answers were a great help to my understanding

Comment: @user112533 Anything for a fellow mathematician!

Answer (score 1):

The first part is simple. Suppose $f(x) = ax^n$for an even integer $n$. $f(-x) = a(-x)^n = ax^n = f(x)$ since $n$ is even.

As for the second part, suppose $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ for each $x$ in the domain of $h$, where $f$ and $g$ are even functions. Then, $h(-x) = f(-x) + g(-x) = f(x) + g(x) = h(x) $

If you are unsure about the definition of an even function then check [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenFunction.html) out.